# python tree directories unique names, tree algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, directory-traversal

I'm working with terrible system which has implemented directory tree structure and support import of this structure in a "strange way", because
import support only format `child;parent`.
Import constraints:
- child items must have unique name
- if parent item is duplicated, child gets imported under first parent found

assume having following structure of directories to be created

```
root
|-- A
|   |-- aa
|   |   |-- cc
|   |   `-- dd
|   `-- bb
|       `-- ee
`-- B
    |-- aa
    |   |-- cc
    |   `-- dd
    `-- bb
        `-- FF
```

How would default import look, which does not work or produce wrong representation:

```
child;parent
root
A;root
aa;A
cc;aa
dd;aa
bb;A
ee;bb
B;root
aa;B   <-- duplicated child item does not work
cc;aa  <-- duplicated entry - system saves it under A instead of under B
dd;aa  <-- duplicated entry - system saves it under A instead of under B
bb;B
FF;bb <-- system saves it under A instead of under B
```

Wrong representation

```
root
|-- A
|   |-- aa
|   |   |-- cc
|   |   `-- dd
|   `-- bb
|       |-- FF
|       `-- ee
`-- B
    `-- aa
        |-- cc
        `-- dd
```

To tackle this problem I decided to rename every folder with unique string `=id` + additional changes (shorter name, etc to fit system requirements)
and imported it into a system, then removed `=id` via database.
then import pairs looks like:

```
child;parent
root;
A==1;root=0
aa=2;A=1
cc=3;aa=2
dd=4;aa=2
bb=5;A=1
ee=7;bb=3
B=8;root=0
aa=9;B=8   
cc=10;aa=9 
dd=11;aa=9  
bb=12;B=8
FF=13;bb=12
```

And the structure is as desired

```
root=0
|-- A=1
|   |-- aa=2
|   |   |-- cc=3
|   |   `-- dd=4
|   `-- bb=5
|       `-- ee=7
`-- B=8
    |-- aa=9
    |   |-- cc=10
    |   `-- dd=11
    `-- bb=12
        `-- FF=13
```

However I need to work with need to work with original structure without renaming it.
I had an idea that I could keep the structure just in memory using tree data structure, but I got stuck in implementation.

I wanted to use `os.walk('root')` and `treelib` but I need help implementing this.

All tips highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way how to have references for original and renamed directories

I used the `treelib` because every `node` can contain `tag, identifier, data`,
and extended `treelib.Tree` by method `create_from_path`.
for this path: `root/A/bb/cc/dd`

Then split the given path `root/A/bb/cc/dd` into portions and visiting every node + updating if already exists:
using this template:
`treelib.Node(tag=unique_name, identifier=full_path, data=base_name)`

`root` -> `Node(root=1, root, root)`
`root/A` -> `Node(A=2, root/A, A)`
`root/A/bb` -> `Node(bb=3, root/A/bb, bb)`
`root/A/bb/cc`-> `Node(cc=4, root/A/bb/cc, cc)`
`root/A/bb/cc/dd` -> `Node(dd=5, root/A/bb/cc/dd, dd)`

Then I could traverse through the tree and build desired paths like:
`root=1/A=2/bb=3/cc=4/dd=5`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that in your system all the names of the directories seem to be in the same scope. This is not solvable without renaming the folders. However instead of just indexing every folder my approach would be to encode the parent structure in the name. For your example your code would look something like this:

```
child;parent
root
root/A;root
root/A/aa;root/A
root/A/aa/cc;root/A/aa
...
root/B;root
root/B/aa;root/B   <-- not duplicated anymore.
...
```

However there might be problems with this approach since directory names can become really long. What access do you have to the system, can you modify it? If I understand you correctly it is used to create a folder structure? Then it seems that the system does not support having children inside different directories with the same name. My presented approach is easy if you use bash to generate the import file (from an already existing directory structure), since the command `pwd` gives you the absolute path to a directory.

If you have access to modify the system a solution would be to have a dict in each folder node (to avoid name collisions) and then having the following import file:

```
child;parent
root
A;root
aa;root/A
cc;root/A/aa
...
B;root
aa;root/B
...
```

so you have just the name of the child and then the explicit path in the parent. Then you can just traverse along the parent path from the root to find the parent node.

Comment: Thank you Mans, I've tried this approach before but I found a lot of limits which even developers were not able to tell me.. And I'm in the role of supporting this crap.

I found the how to it with treelib, I'll post my solution later